# my NPC's are living in the wrong houses

Tags: terraria

I have started a village, and I want Non Player Characters in certain houses. Is there anyway to move them around?

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution to doing this is the housing interface. However, since you can only have one NPC in a house at a time, make an empty house to help with the re-arranging.

Open up your inventory (`ESC`) and just above your armor/accessories area, you will find a little house icon. Click on that.

To move an NPC's house, click on their name, and click on their new house. You will know that the NPC has moved house if a banner with their face appears in there house. Just repeat the process with the other NPCs until everyone is in their correct house. Note that the NPCs probably won't move into their new house until night.

Once everyone is moved, click on the house icon again to close the housing interface.